# How can I see which location has the most reviews/ratings in a given area on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I see which location has the most reviews/ratings in a given area on the Google Maps Android application?

Using the "Top Rated" filter doesn't sort by number of reviews/ratings:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There does not seem to be any option directly in the Google Maps app to do this. However, the [Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37462004/5987698) provides this information for developers.

Searching further, [this website](https://www.top-rated.online/) seems to provide an approximation of what you are looking for, probably using the API. You can search for top rated places in a given city, filter by place type, and also view all the places on a map.

Screenshot for reference:
[image]